# Why does my pam work for sudo and not for ssh?

Tags: authentication, ssh, pam

I have written a PAM module that displays a QR-code when we do the `$ sudo su` command. The PAM only displays the QR code, no verification is made and no password is asked.

I tried to use this PAM with ssh but nothing is displayed on the screen. Does anybody know why ?

Comment: So I found out that all my calls to the printf function were in the pam_sm_authenticate function, which apparently not called when I log to ssh localhost. By putting them in pam_sm_setcred I can now see them on the screen, my qr code is still not displayed though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have half of a qr code...
This function is drawing the qr code on the terminal :

```
void output_ansi(FILE * file, const struct qr_bitmap * bmp)
{
     const char * out[2] = {
            "  ",
            "\033[7m  \033[0m",
    };

    unsigned char * line;
    size_t x, y;

    line = bmp->bits;

    for (y = 0; y < bmp->height; ++y) {

        fprintf(file, "%d\n",y );

            for (x = 0; x < bmp->width; ++x) {

                    int mask = 1 << (x % CHAR_BIT);
                    int byte = line[x / CHAR_BIT];

                    fprintf(file, "%s", out[!!(byte & mask)]);
            }

            fputc('\n', file);

            line += bmp->stride;
    }
 }
```

But by displaying the value of y in the for loop, I noticed that the first 9 lines are not printed... does anybody know what is the problem ?

Comment: I fixed the problem by using fflush before calling the function